# Unable to save push notification message data?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, push-notification

I want to save my iPhone push notification message data in to my plist. It is working when i select View button but I unable to save it on select close button. Please help me.

thanks

Answer (score 2):

The app will be launched only if the user taps the `action` button. If the user taps the `Cancel` button, the notification will be just ignored and there is no way you can get the data(`userInfo`) from it.